# Override Local Data in Siesta?

Tags: ios, swift, siesta-swift

I'm having trouble successfully setting local data for Siesta in Swift. My goal is to set a `UIImage` for a `URL` locally, so that this local image can be displayed with no download time.

To do this, I'm setting the image data for the URL as such:

```
let resource = CustomRemoteImageView.imageCache.resource(myPhoto.url.absoluteString)
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)! // I've also tried putting the UIImage directly in there, because the transformation chain doesn't apply to local data, right?
let entity: Entity<Any> = Entity(content: imageData, contentType: "*/*") // I've played around with the content type too!
resource.overrideLocalData(with: entity)
```

I'm then using a custom Service that always tries to parse content as an Image:

```
private let imageTransformer =
    ResponseContentTransformer
        { Image(data: $0.content)}

convenience init() {
    self.init(standardTransformers: [])
    configure {
        $0.pipeline[PipelineStageKey.parsing].add(self.imageTransformer, contentTypes: ["*/*"])
    }
}
```

This system is working great for all remote images, but it always seems to fail to parse this overridden local image. It seems like it's *trying* to parse but just fails every time.

i.e. I'm getting a `Siesta.ResourceEvent` of

```
(Siesta.ResourceEvent) $R20 = newData {
  newData = network
}
```

but the actual `.typedContent` is `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

`overrideLocalData` and `overrideLocalContent` do not interact with the pipeline at all. Siesta won’t try to parse what you pass; what you override is what your resource gets.

Furthermore, `overrideLocalData` and `overrideLocalContent` don’t fail. They *always* update the resource’s content. If you call those methods, the resource content will match what you passed.

So … the problem isn’t parsing. What might it be?

`Entity.typedContent` is a shortcut for applying `as?` to a resource’s entity’s `content`. If you're getting nil, it means that either (1) the `content` of the entity you passed to the `overrideLocalData` was nil or (2) the contextual type in which you’re calling `typedContent` doesn’t match the `content`’s actual runtime type.

What do you see if you print `resource.latestData.content`? That will show you what’s actually there, and will rule out type conversion issues with `typedContent`.

If it’s not nil, compare its value from a network request and get the types to match.

If it is nil, then either something else cleared the content or you passed nil content in the first place. Try `SiestaLog.Category.enabled = .common` and see if you can spot where it is or isn’t getting set to the right thing.